# Multiple http request in one request to different domain

Tags: http, url, web, tcp, cross-domain

May be this is an awkward question due to my lack of knowledge and I don't know which topic I should search to know about this, but I kind of hope/wish there was a solution.

What I mean is there any way I could send http requests to multiple domains ?

For eg: If I send an http request for a page www.facebook.com/stackoverflow.
I want a simple info that this link is clicked by someone by sending a message to my domain also.The URL can be changed to anything with primary URL still as main source.

What I mean plainly is

www.facebook.com/stackoverflow+{additional code to some way a request to my website also }

Answer (score 1):

When you send a request for `http://www.facebook.com/stackoverflow`, it requires making a TCP connection to `www.facebook.com`'s server and then sending an HTTP request for the `/stackoverflow` resource on that server.  You can't make Facebook forward the same request to another server.

If you want the link to request your domain, you have to declare your domain as the target of the link. You can specify another URL as an extra parameter, so your domain can use an HTTP redirect to forward the client to that URL when ready.  For instance, search engines do this all the time to track the links that users click on in search results.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/doSomething?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstackoverflow
```

The client would connect to the `www.example.com` server and send a request for  `/doSomething?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstackoverflow`. A script located at `/doSomething` can do whatever it needs to do, and then redirect the client to the URL in the `goto` parameter (`http://www.facebook.com/stackoverflow`).